Wheel Build error while installing LLama-CPP-Python on python
I was trying to install llama-cpp-python but I am getting wheel building error.
I have installed Cmake and getting error regarding the compiler setup which is done.
I tried to run make file but I am not getting over this error:
 Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      *** scikit-build-core 0.10.7 using CMake 3.30.4 (wheel)
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2024-09-28 19:32:29,171 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=None, ldlibrary=None, multiarch=None, masd=None
      loading initial cache file C:\Users\giria\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpm31km1cb\build\CMakeInit.txt
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         no such file or directory


      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

      *** CMake configuration failed
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
Failed to build llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
this is the error

